# Current flowing through an $LR$ circuit at any given time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, inductance

I was solving some physics problems and saw a question that used a formula for current flowing in $LR$ circuit in $t$th second.

The equation is given as:

[image: R-L circuit and equation for current]

I was wondering how this equation is derived as I've never seen it being used before.

Any resources for further information would help too.

Answer (score 3):

Kirchoff's loop rule states that the voltage changes in a closed loop must sum to 0.

Therefore $V - IR - L\frac{dI}{dt} = 0$.

You can verify that $I(t) = \frac{V}{R}(1 - e^{\frac{-Rt}{L}})$ is a solution to that differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

You do indeed use Kirchhoff's voltage law to get a differential equation $V=L\dfrac {dI}{dt} +IR$ and then solve it to get your resulting equation.

However you can predict the general shape of the current against time graph without solving the differential equation.

$\dfrac {dI}{dt}= \dfrac VL - \dfrac {IR}{L}$

At time $t=0$ the current $I=0$ and gradient of the current against time graph is $\dfrac VL$.

A little later in time, $t_1$, with a current flowing the gradient of the graph is less than $\dfrac VL$ by an amount $\dfrac {IR}{L}$.

[image]

So as time progresses the gradient decrease towards zero and the current tends to $\dfrac VR$.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other two good answer I will provide some hints on how to solve the differential equation
$$\frac{dI}{dt}=-\frac R LI+\frac V L\tag{1}.$$
First, notice that if the term $V/L$ was not here the solution would be simply
$$I(t)=Ce^{-\frac R Lt}$$
with some unknown constant $C$. But we can make a simple substition to get rid of the constant term. We can write $I(t)=I'(t)+I_0$, which results in $\frac{dI}{dt}=\frac{dI'}{dt}$. Which value of $I_0$ should you choose such that the constant term disappears?

You can now solve the differential equation and re-substitute $I(t)$. We now have to use $I(0)=0$. This condition is not obvious and should be specified in the problem. We can imagine there being a switch in the circuit and at $t=0$ we turn on the switch.

Finally I will provide some intuition on this setup. An inductor is basically an electromagnet: it will create a magnetic field that is proportional to the current around it. Changing this magnetic field costs energy, but once it has been set up it will not cost further energy to maintain it.

While the current is changing, there will be voltage over the inductor proportional to the change in current. This fact is a reflection of a fact that energy is used to set up a magnetic field: the power is proportional to voltage , $P=VI$, and the power is proportional to the change in current because of what I mentioned in the previous paragraph. So we have $V\propto \frac{dI}{dt}$ and we call the proportionality constant the inductance: $V=L\frac{dI}{dt}$.

Right when the switch is turned on, the inductor is able to briefly keep the voltage at zero. At $t=0$ the change in current is $\dot I(0)=V/L$. The voltage over the inductor is $L\dot I(0)=V$. This means the voltage over the resistor is zero and this means the current through the circuit is zero. After $t=0$ the current slowly starts building. The energy loss through the resistor increases and as the current grows more power will go to waste heat in the resistor instead of to increasing the magnetic field in the inductor. Finally, the circuit will reach equilibrium when the voltage over the resistor is $V$ and the voltage over the inductor is zero.

Putting this together, an inductor basically acts like inertia for the current. If we had no inductor, we could instantly switch the current by flipping the switch. But with it, the current slowly reaches equilibrium.